# bpython configuration - importing numpy and matplotlib by default

Tags: python, numpy, bpython

Is it possible to start the [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org/) interpreter so that it always runs some custom commands when it launches?

In my case I simply want to do:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I can't see anything in the [docs](http://docs.bpython-interpreter.org/configuration.html). Anyone know a way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is written in the docs, just not clearly labelled as such at: http://docs.bpython-interpreter.org/django.html

Gist of it is you can have an environment variable called `PYTHONSTARTUP`. bpython will execute this file before you get dropped in the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

While ikanobori's answer is the way to go here, I thought I show another simple alternative.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import bpython
bpython.embed(locals_=locals())
```

This will start up the bpython REPL and load in the local variables and other symbols. This would be useful if you wanted to have more than one customized shell.